# set vars in bat files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

ok, heres my question straight to the point:
ive used set /p in my bat script:

```
SET x= 
SET /P x= 
IF /I '%x%' == '1' GOTO 1
IF /I '%x%' == '2' GOTO 2
IF /I '%x%' == '3' GOTO 3
IF /I '%x%' == '4' GOTO 4
IF /I '%x%' == '5' GOTO 5
```

and my issue is, if someone types something out of ordinary (eg. 6) I want the command to be goto a (so they get back to the menu)
so is there a way to do it ? like using %errorlevel% or "else" ? thanks!

Comment: I'd use the `choice` command if you aren't on XP. Also, I should point out that `/i` is for case-insensitive comparisons and you're checking numerical values (it will still work, it's just unnecessary).

Comment: @SomethingDark its because it isnt really numbers, I just showed numbers to make it less complex for you to explain :P thanq anyway

Answer (score 2):

```
:repeat
SET "x=" 
SET /P "x=enter x:" 
IF /I "%x%" == "1" GOTO 1
IF /I "%x%" == "2" GOTO 2
IF /I "%x%" == "3" GOTO 3
IF /I "%x%" == "4" GOTO 4
IF /I "%x%" == "5" GOTO 5
echo invalid input
goto :repeat
:1
...
:2
....
```

if you set `goto :repeat` before all other labels it will repeat the prompting if the input is invalid and will be skipped if it is.

Comment: ok, ive also notice that if I insert and intput that includes a space or just press enter without any input it just gets an error and doesnt even go to the "invalid input" area and just exits cmd...any help?

Comment: @AdamTheCarpenter  - use double quotes in comparisons - fixed in my answer now - to force taking the arguments as strings.